# How can I stack an image over text?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to line up images horizontally and directly under these images I want to apply text, how would I go about doing so?

This is what I have tried in my last attempt and so far...no luck!

I am also using bootstrap and doing this styling in a ruby on rails application, if that helps. THANK YOU!

HTML

```
<div class="our-story-pt-5">
  <div class="container">
    <h4>Our services include</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img class="img-responsive" src="img-1.jpg">
          <p>Creative and Technology Strategy</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
        <li>
          <img class="img-responsive" src="img-2.jpg">
          <p>Digital Product Development</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img class="img-responsive" src="img-3.jpg">
          <p>Technology Integration</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img class="img-responsive" src="img-4.jpg">
          <p>System Validation</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img class="img-responsive" src="img-5.jpg"><br>
          <p>Sustained Support and Enhancement</p>
        </li>
      </ul><!-- end ul -->
    </div><!-- end div.row -->
  </div><!-- end div.container -->
</div><!-- end div.our-story-pt-5 -->
```

CSS

```
div.our-story-pt-5 ul{
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
}

div.our-story-pt-5 li{
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #284179;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 22px;
  display: inline;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  p{
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: 'Gotham-Bold';
    line-height: 23px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #2c4d82;
  }
}

div.our-story-pt-5 img{
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.img-responsive{
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using Bootstrap's own "col-xx-xx" classes to align your content perfectly next to each other? This would be even better than using a UL>LI, which, I believe, doesn't really fit in the structure

Comment: I tried using small columns to align the content however I still could not get all the text under the image @IndieRok

Answer (score 0):

What about this? Using Bootstrap column classes and a few lines of CSS to center the text, I believe the result to be what you are looking for. Of course, you could use the offset classes if you would really wish the last two box to be centered. But that's for you to decide.

[Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/chgO9f7VR1)

HTML:

```
<div class="our-story-pt-5">
  <div class="container">
    <h4>Our services include</h4>
    <div class="row">      
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 item-box">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://static.alipson.fr/m124/p97072/p1.jpg">
          <p>Creative and Technology Strategy</p>
        </div>      
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 item-box">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://dolceamaro.d.o.pic.centerblog.net/66vpjvnj.jpg">
          <p>Digital Product Development</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 item-box">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://static.alipson.fr/m124/p32420/p1.jpg">
          <p>Technology Integration</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 item-box">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/432550536768802816/Ht4nqkAi_400x400.png">
          <p>System Validation</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 item-box">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://tonij.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2014/08/derp-dragon-for-blog-400x400.jpg"><br>
          <p>Sustained Support and Enhancement</p>
        </div>      
    </div><!-- end div.row -->
  </div><!-- end div.container -->
</div><!-- end div.our-story-pt-5 -->
```

CSS:

```
.item-box{
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:25px;
}

div.our-story-pt-5 ul{
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
}

div.our-story-pt-5 li{
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #284179;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 22px;
  display: inline;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  p{
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: 'Gotham-Bold';
    line-height: 23px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #2c4d82;
  }
}

div.our-story-pt-5 img{
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.img-responsive{
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a few ways you can do this depending on if you want to use the grid or not. If not then just use display: inline-block on your `li` and maybe give your `ul` a class (though not necessary).

See examples in Snippet.

```css
.our-story-pt-5 ul.img-container li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.our-story-pt-5 ul.img-container img {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.our-story-pt-5 ul.img-container {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
.our-story-pt-5 ul.img-container li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #284179;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  p {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: 'Gotham-Bold';
    line-height: 23px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #2c4d82;
  }
}
/**Grid**/

.our-story-pt-6 {
  color: #284179;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  p {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: 'Gotham-Bold';
    line-height: 23px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #2c4d82;
  }
}
.our-story-pt-6 img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="our-story-pt-5 text-center">
  <h3 class="well well-sm">List</h3>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h4>Our services include</h4>

    <ul class="img-container">
      <li>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <p>Creative and Technology Strategy</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <p>Digital Product Development</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <p>Technology Integration</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <p>System Validation</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <p>Sustained Support and Enhancement</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="our-story-pt-6 text-center">
  <h3 class="well well-sm">Grid 1</h3>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h4>Our services include</h4>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <p>Creative and Technology Strategy</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <p>Digital Product Development</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <p>Technology Integration</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <p>System Validation</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <p>Sustained Support and Enhancement</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="our-story-pt-6 text-center">
  <h3 class="well well-sm">Grid 2</h3>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h4>Our services include</h4>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <p>Creative and Technology Strategy</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <p>Digital Product Development</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <p>Technology Integration</p>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix visible-md-block visible-sm-block"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <p>System Validation</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <p>Sustained Support and Enhancement</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify CSS on your code::

```
        div.our-story-pt-5 ul{
          list-style: none;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 0px;
        }

        div.our-story-pt-5 li{
          list-style-type: none;
          color: #284179;
          text-align: center;
          line-height: 40px;
          font-size: 22px;
          display: inline;
          width: 19%;
          padding: 0px 5px;
          float: left;
        }
        p{
            font-weight: 500;
            font-family: 'Gotham-Bold';
            line-height: 23px;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            letter-spacing: 0px;
            color: #2c4d82;
        }
        h4 {
          font-size: 30px;
          text-align: center;
        }
        div.our-story-pt-5 img{
          margin-bottom: 12px;
        }

        .img-responsive{
          display: inline-block;
          height: auto;
          max-width: 100%;
        }
```

HTML::

```
    <div class="our-story-pt-5">
        <div class="container">
            <h4>Our services include</h4>
            <div class="row">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/122/a-cute-panda-isolated_122428798.jpg">
                      <p>Creative and Technology Strategy</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/122/a-cute-panda-isolated_122428798.jpg">
                      <p>Digital Product Development</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/122/a-cute-panda-isolated_122428798.jpg">
                      <p>Technology Integration</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/122/a-cute-panda-isolated_122428798.jpg">
                      <p>System Validation</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/122/a-cute-panda-isolated_122428798.jpg"><br>
                      <p>Sustained Support and Enhancement</p>
                    </li>
                </ul><!-- end ul -->
            </div><!-- end div.row -->
        </div><!-- end div.container -->
    </div><!-- end div.our-story-pt-5 -->
```

!!!Very simple
USING BOOTSTRAP::

```
    <div class="our-story-pt-5">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="text-center">Our services include</h2>
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/122/a-cute-panda-isolated_122428798.jpg">
                        <p>Creative and Technology Strategy</p>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/122/a-cute-panda-isolated_122428798.jpg">
                        <p>Digital Product Development</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/122/a-cute-panda-isolated_122428798.jpg">
                        <p>Technology Integration</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/122/a-cute-panda-isolated_122428798.jpg">
                        <p>System Validation</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/122/a-cute-panda-isolated_122428798.jpg">
                        <p>Sustained Support and Enhancement</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end div.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- end div.container -->
    </div>
    <!-- end div.our-story-pt-5 -->
```